# V is a random variable, find PDF of W=ln(v) ? Help.

Tags: calculus, probability

If W is an exponential random variable with parameter lambda= 1, find the probability density function of the random variable w = ln v.

My work:

Then,
Range of w : (-infiniti, infitini)
Range of v: (0, infinity)

Fw[w]=P[W<=w]=P[ln(v)<=w]=P[v<=exp(w)]=Fv[exp(w)]

Differentiating fv(v)=F'v(exp(w))=fv(exp(w)) d/dw {exp(w)}= fw(exp(w)) exp(w)

for all w.

---

I don't know if is correct what I did or if I am missing something important. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You concluded correctly that $F_W(w)=F_V(e^w)$. Also we *know* the distribution of $V$ so: $$f_W(w)=f_V(e^w)e^w=e^{-e^w}e^w=e^{w-e^w}$$

More directly you can derive this by differentiating the RHS of $F_W(w)=F_V(e^w)=1-e^{-e^w}$

Comment: Before all thanks for your response. I'm not quit understand from where this fv(e^w)*e^w is equal to e^(-e^w). Also, I don't understand how this last term is equal to e^(-w*e^w). I tough be equal to e(w-e^w). Thanks you.

Comment: You are correct again. I made a typo and repaired it (sorry). $f_V(v)=e^{-v}$ as PDF of exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda=1$. Substituting $v=e^w$ then leads to $f_V(e^w)=e^{-e^w}$. Multiplying this with $e^w$ finally gives $e^{w-e^w}$.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Drhab.

Comment: You are very welcome!